# How can I remove rust from steel cabinet hinges?

Tags: hinges, rust-removal, rust-proofing, rust, stainless

While many of the hinges are fine while some of them have developed rust. I'm annoyed about the fact that it got rusted within months of installation but I'm wondering what I can do to remove the rust and extend it's lifetime.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Would let the store know they are rusting.  Good chance cheap plated hinges were in the lot.

Comment: Do you have acid or bleach in there?

Comment: Not SS , apparently chrome plated ( and not very good).

Comment: What made you think that was stainless?  Being shiny does not make it stainless, just chrome plated.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - I bought this [brand ebco stainless steel hinges](https://ebco.in/hinges/euro-slip-on-hinge-ss304) , I think he might have given some fake hinges along with that.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - I can buy acid and bleach locally here

Comment: @blacksmith37 - seems like chrome plated only.

Comment: Amogam, there is nothing in the description of the hinges that indicate they are stainless.

Comment: @Amogam Question was (I could have said it more clearly) **are you storing acid or bleach in the cabinet** - both of those tend to promote rusting if not very carefully sealed. Usually not a good rust removal choice, though a citric acid solution can be used for rust removal if not left too long.

Comment: I'm mostly storing the books and there are some chalk piece over there other than that the room is Air conditioned don't know whenever the temperature drops due AC usage , it causes some kind of issue with hinge ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have in the picture is not a stainless steel hinge.
You are best to replace it. What is in the cabinet that hinges services?
The only time I had a cabinet hinge rust like that it was where My wife stored chlorine tablets. There is something causing rapid oxidation in that cabinet. You will not be able to stop the rusting until you remove the source of the oxidation, or you may have to resort to marine grade hinges of a different design. I do not know of any stainless cabinet hinges that are a direct replacement.

Comment: The room has Air conditioner other than that I don't see anything that can influence the oxidation.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to get rid of the rust and treat the hinge to extend it's life ?

Comment: You can wire brush off the rust. It will come back quickly until you remove the source of the oxidation.  Again, what is stored in the cabinet, not in the room?

Comment: Thanks.I will check again. But after removing the rust is there anything that I can apply on top of the hinge ?

Comment: You can try spray painting. However if the oxidizing fumes remain in the cabinet you will have the same result.  There is no magic fix for that hinge.

Comment: Can AC increase the oxidization of the hinges ?

Comment: If you are referring to air conditioning of the interior air, then no.  Ac generally pulls humidity from the air and making it less of a stimulus to oxidation.

Comment: that makes sense

Comment: you can use electrolysis to remove rust without affecting non-rust areas; a 12v battery and some baking soda is about all you need.

Comment: That seems like a good solution.Please lemme know more about this. Thanks :)